# Prime Numbers: What is wrong in my code? It works fine for till int limits as I go for long the code is taking a lot time

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, math, prime-factoring

```
public class PrimeNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1000000000;
        int m=2;
        int n=1;
        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            int l=0;
            if(j%25==0)
            {
                if(j%100==0)
                {
                    m++;
                }
                if(j%1000==0)
                {
                    m++;
                }
                m++;
            }
            if (j % 2 != 0) {
                for (int k = 2; k < j/m; k++) {
                    if (j % k == 0) {
                        l++;
                    }
                }
                if (l < 1) {
                    n++;
                }
                if(n==1001)
                {
                    System.out.print(j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine for numbers till ~100 million but as I'm going for larger numbers the result is inconsistent. I've seen the algorithms for prime numbers, just thought of trying.

Comment: What is the code _supposed_ to do, and what is it actually doing.  "doesn't work" is not an acceptable explanation.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: What are these letters? It's convention to use names which are descriptive.

Comment: You should go to http://cs.stackexchange.com/.  They sort out mathematical algorithms.

Comment: By the way, the repeated division algorithm is from 2 to the square root of N. I'm not sure what `m % 25 == 0` does, but that isn't the square root function.

Comment: One thing to try. Check which is the last correct number that printed.  Have a conditional break point at that number.  Then step through the code. Of perhaps have the break point just before the incorrect number, with a conditional break point.

Comment: "The code I wrote for my homework doesn't work" is not a question.  It's a story.  And not even an interesting one.  Please come back when you can point to a _specific_ problem with _specific_ code.  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I'm decreasing the value of m as the number increases so that there'll be less iterations since you don't need to go through all the numbers.

Comment: I don't know what it is supposed to do, but currently it prints the 1001. prime number and the following odd numbers up to (but not including) the 1002. prime number

Answer (score 2):

int's are limited to represent numbers to approx. 2.1 billion. Past that the integer will begin to wrap around. Use the `long` data type instead and you will be able to go much higher.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you are trying to do exactly, but what i judge you want to identify the prime numbers until the number you have specified... if this is what you need, here is the code:

```
public class PrimeNumbers {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 20000;
        int i = 1;
        int j = 0;
        while (i <= number) {
            j = 1;
            int counter = 0;
            while (j <= i){
                int divide = i / j;
                if (i % j == 0){
                    counter++;
                }
                j++;                
            }
            if (counter <= 2) {
                System.out.print(i + "   ");
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```